# mapping a curl command to equal python requests function

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

Really would appreciate some help to understand what I'm missing.
I have a working curl command that I need to map to an equal python function using requests.

All my attempts end up failing with a message of : 
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))

The original curl command is:
    curl -X POST "https://x.x.x.x/api/upload" -H "accept: application/json" 
    -H "authorization: Basic BlaBla" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
    -F "file=@SomeFile.zip;type=application/zip"

My failing python code is:

```
def importZip(self, fAuth, infile, dir=''):
    trgtURL = fAuth.url+"/api/upload"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    data = {'upload':''}
    files = {'file': (infile, open(dir+infile,'rb'))}
    r = fAuth.session.post(trgtURL, files=files, data=data)
```

fAuth is just a class I use to authenticate and retain the session for follow up calls. I can use the fAuth instance to do gets no problem, so I suspect the problem isn't tied to the underlying session.
Any ideas or insight are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. `-H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` equal to `{"Accept": "application/json"}` in python. `Content-Type` is not necessary, because library will add it.
2. `-H "authorization: Basic BlaBla"` is a bit special in header. So you should read [Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)

So you job is to add auth param, and modify your headers by your command example.

```
def importZip(self, fAuth, infile, dir=''):
    trgtURL = fAuth.url+"/api/upload"
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    files = {'file': (infile, open(dir+infile,'rb'), "application/zip")}
    auth = (user,passwd)
    r = fAuth.session.post(trgtURL, headers=headers, files=files, auth=auth)
```